# Where to store videos in projects

Tags: c#, wpf, video, media

I wonder if the videos (used in project) should be stored as resources. If it's a good way of managing such a sort of media, how to use `MediaElement` to play these videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, as usual.

Some very short videos, like the CopyFile animations in Windows can be stored as resources.

But for larger videos that's not a very good choice.
Another factor might be: how often will they change?

Usually they are deployed as files in a separate folder.

Comment: Hmm, I see. My files are 1-10MB large (I use them rarely). I wanted to create a new project (to clean everything up) which contains only video resources.

Comment: A separate assembly for a number of short and stable videos looks OK.